# How to avoid multiple AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm submitting a form via AJAX using the code below:

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'str': $( 'form' ).serialize()
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            // Do something here.
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            // Do something here.
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Background**

My PHP handler carries out various tasks and then sends back a response. I can then do something with `data` in either of the success or error functions.

**My problem**

When a user double clicks on the form's submit button, two AJAX calls take place which causes the code inside my PHP handler to execute twice.

**My question**

How can I avoid my code being executed twice if a user double clicks on submit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable the submit button on the first click and re-enable it, when the AJAX call comes back.

For example:

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('submit').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'str': $( 'form' ).serialize()
        },
        complete: function() {
            $form.find('submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            // Do something here.
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            // Do something here.
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Antoniossss It will work for any tags which can be disabled (submit, input, select). For others you can use a class to change to a disabled style.

Comment: Thats why I used flag insteed of DOM modification. Upvote anyway.

Comment: Yes, a flag is a good way to do this. But I like that this way shows the user that work is being done and clicking the button again won't do anything now.

Answer (score 15):

Just add there some control variable:

```
var isSubmitting = false;

$( 'form' ).submit(function(e) {
    if(isSubmitting) {
        return;
    }
    isSubmitting = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'str': $( 'form' ).serialize()
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            isSubmitting = false;
            // Do something here.
        },
            error: function( data ) {
            isSubmitting = false;
            // Do something here.
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This quite possibly deserves to be the accepted answer, but I kinda like the idea of disabling the button (which shows something is happening). Please accept a +1 instead. Thanks!

Comment: always: function(data) { isSubmitting = true; } encompasses all cases

Comment: @henrywright true, disabling button looks nice, but what if event target is not disablable? eg <i> tag whitch is commonly used if you use font-awesome. This should be accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide and show the submit button on submit.

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function(e) {
  $('#my_button').hide();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'str': $( 'form' ).serialize()
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        // Do something here.
    },
    error: function( data ) {
        // Do something here.
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#my_button').show();
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: Hiding the button is possible but could have side effects if other buttons or elements on the page move into the free space.

Comment: That would be awkward... he could also block the form using something like BlockUI and make it look fancy; K.I.S.S. instead :v